# How do I use nodes to combine two images when both have transparent areas?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to use nodes to combine two images if both the images have transparency (i.e. alpha channels)?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use an *Alpha over* node to automatically handle the alpha mixing:

[image]

However, if all you want to do is mix the alpha channels, a normal mix node will do (think of the alpha channel as a gray scale image):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

There are a few ways to do this. I will show you the way that worked for me. I drew some images in photoshop with alpha. Here is how to combine two images with alpha using the blender compositor. I found that this is the most reliable method to use for external images.

**Final Node Setup:**

[image]

**Final Result:**

[image]