# How to place an overlay video with a transparent background upon another video/image?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor

First off, I'm a novice to node compositing, so I might not understand some jargons.

Below is the original video.  [image]

Next photo: the white background is removed (my first time with invert node). The background is turned transparent. Now how do I lay this overlay upon another video or image with any different colour? 
I'd like to try medium brown ground or yellow for the lower ground.
[image]

Comment: *Alpha Over* node usually does the trick

Comment: @Duarte, I had tried Alpha Over before and failed. I think I have used it wrong, but I will try it again tomorrow (my computer at work). I will try your suggestion, when I follow instructions at this thread from the past: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7782/how-do-i-use-nodes-to-combine-two-images-when-both-have-transparent-areas. Thank you for suggesting Alpha Over node.

Comment: You may find this link useful .... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50771/rotoscoping-to-a-transparent-background/50776#50776

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and worked out the solutions. I got the desired result. Thanks, Duarte and Atomicbezierslinger

Answer (score 2):

The next day... 
I have tried Alpha Over as was suggested. Initially, it was tricky and difficult to work with nodes, while making mistakes. Now, I have finally achieved the desired result and here I enclose the screenshot. [image]

Comment: If your problem was solved by your solution, you should mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Leander, are you sure? Originally, I thought that might be cheating, if I ticked my own answer as accepted and gave myself 15 points. That was what I thought previously.

Comment: Read the 2nd bullet point from [accepting an answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). There will be no change in reputation points. You can also change the accepted answer anytime if another answer is written.