# Compositing: Can I have multiple masks in one composite?

Tags: compositing-nodes

To have one mask on a comp it will follow this compositing node flow:

**Render layerA** of Mask (Alpha) -connects to- **Mix** (Factor)

**Render layerB** of BG (Image) -connects to-   **Mix** (Image1)

**Render layerC** of MaskBG (Image) -connects to- **Mix** (Image2)

From this one Mix node is created one complete image, but using just one masked area.

I need to create an image with *multiple* mask areas.  How do I do it?

The problem I run into is that I don't know what node I would need to combine multiple masks onto the one background image.

Please help.  :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7782/how-do-i-use-nodes-to-combine-two-images-when-both-have-transparent-areas and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86617/how-to-stack-layer-two-textures-with-alpha-over-each-other-with-material-nodes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137

Answer (score 1):

Stop looking!  I've worked it out.  :D

The answer is: Once you create one image using an alpha mask you then use this as your background layer for the NEXT alpha mask, and so on, and so on.

It felt like a puzzle in a computer game that I just solved. Now I'm on the next level.

Sweet!

Comment: As far as I understand it, it is equivalent to taking all masks and multiplying their alphas using *Math* nodes. Except if you multiply, your result will be more accurate, because you won't flatten the alpha value to an 8-bit value after each multiplication.